# Is it possible to create HTML items from JS in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have simple `GET` request, which brings some data to show.

```
this.apiRequest.get(url)
.map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(response => {
    this.notes = response.notes

    loader.dismiss()
}, err => {
    loader.dismiss()
})
```

Then I show it like this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let note of notes" text-wrap>
    <!-- data -->
</ion-item>
```

The main problem is that when there is a lot of `notes` the loader dismisses before all items are shown.

I need loop `ngFor` in js and then hide loader or somehow disable loader from `HTML`...

Answer (score 1):

this is not what you are looking for but hope will help

Base idea is to provide `ngFor` loop complete event

Create component

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'islast',
   template: '<span></span>'
})
export class LastDirective {
   @Input() isLast: boolean;
   @Output() onLastDone: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
   ngOnInit() {
      if (this.isLast)
        this.onLastDone.emit(true); //you can hide loader from here this is last element in ngfor
   }
}
```

in html

```
  <tr *ngFor="let sm of filteredMembers; let last = last; let i=index;" data-id="{{sm.Id}}">
     <td>
        <islast [isLast]="last" (onLastDone)="modalMembersDone()">
```